# Can I get link location through selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I have a link on the webpage. I want to right click and copy the link location is it possible through selenium 1?
 For example I have a webpage opened and it has a link "add book" and it manually if i right click and do copy link location then it points to http://webserver/webapps/books/addbook.jsp?book_id=44_1&type=reference&promo=none

Is there a way to find out to copy the link by giving an XPath of the text :"add book" ? Or using javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Am using bellow code to get link location (With Selenium-WebDriver and java binding) :

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("add book"));
String linkLocatin = link.getAttribute("href");
System.out.println("Link Location "+linkLocatin);
```

Comment: thanks Surya, but we are not using webdriver. Directly we are using selenium.

Comment: Okay...In selenium 1.0 you can try bellow code to get link location: String linkLocation = selenium.getAttribute("//a[text()=\"add book\"]@href");

Answer (score 1):

In Selenese I use something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>xpath=//a[text()="add book"]@href</td>
    <td>linkToBook</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${linkToBook}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium-interface has a

```
getHtmlSource()
```

-method. This returns a String, on which you can apply an Xpath like this:

```
//a[text()="add book"]
```